Software to designate a group of windows together such that they are minimized/maximized together?
The idea is to select some windows as a group such that they are min/maximized together while multitasking.
The addition to snapping windows would be to streamline the multitasking process instead of having to re-select the windows to appear next to each other again if you task-switch, for example.
So the app would minimize all grouped windows if you minimize one, etc.
I tried to search for this, but most results are about bulk-minimizing or maximizing windows as you can imagine.

I think that what most of us are using is a multiple virtual desktop application.  Windows supports it natively.  You have different windows open on different desktops and you can rapidly switch between the desktops with hotkeys.
I use VirtuaWin because I prefer it's functionality.  It is free and I have no association with it.
